# Acceder a una variable desde otro metodo en c#

Tags: c#

Quiero acceder la variable `datos`

```
private CustomValidator ActualizarBodega(decimal idDetPedido, string proceso)
        {
            var error = new CustomValidator();

                var datos = (from GridViewRow row in bodegasGridView.Rows
                let bodega = (Label) row.FindControl("bodegaLabel")
                let cantidad = (TextBox) row.FindControl("cantidadTextBox")
                let disponible = (Label) row.FindControl("disponibleLabel")
                let idArticuloBodega = (Label) row.FindControl("idArticuloBodegaLabel")
                let idBodega = (Label) row.FindControl("idBodegaLabel")
                select new DistribucionBodega
                       {
                           Bodega = bodega.Text,
                           Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cantidad.Text) ? "0" : cantidad.Text),
                           Disponible = Convert.ToInt32(disponible.Text),
                           IdArticuloBodega = Convert.ToInt32(idArticuloBodega.Text),
                           IdBodega = Convert.ToDecimal(idBodega.Text)
                       }).ToList();

            if (datos.Sum(t => t.Cantidad) != Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxCantidad.Text))
            {
                error.ErrorMessage = "La cantidad distribuida no concuerda con la cantidad del articulo.";
                return error;
            }
}
```

como accedo a ella o como podria declararla para acceder a ella desde otro metodo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias devlver como respuesta ambos datos si crear una clase como ser

```
public class ActualizarBodegaResult
{
    public List<DistribucionBodega> datos {get;set;}
    public CustomValidator error {get;set;}
}
```

y despues devuelves esta como respuesta

```
private ActualizarBodegaResult ActualizarBodega(GridView bodegasGridView, decimal idDetPedido, string proceso)
{
    var error = new CustomValidator();

    var datos = (from GridViewRow row in bodegasGridView.Rows
                    let bodega = (Label) row.FindControl("bodegaLabel")
                    let cantidad = (TextBox) row.FindControl("cantidadTextBox")
                    let disponible = (Label) row.FindControl("disponibleLabel")
                    let idArticuloBodega = (Label) row.FindControl("idArticuloBodegaLabel")
                    let idBodega = (Label) row.FindControl("idBodegaLabel")
                select new DistribucionBodega
                   {
                       Bodega = bodega.Text,
                       Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cantidad.Text) ? "0" : cantidad.Text),
                       Disponible = Convert.ToInt32(disponible.Text),
                       IdArticuloBodega = Convert.ToInt32(idArticuloBodega.Text),
                       IdBodega = Convert.ToDecimal(idBodega.Text)
                   }).ToList();

    if (datos.Sum(t => t.Cantidad) != Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxCantidad.Text))
    {
        error.ErrorMessage = "La cantidad distribuida no concuerda con la cantidad del articulo.";
    }

    return new ActualizarBodegaResult()
    {
        datos = datos,
        error = error
    }
}
```

Analiza el `return` como devuelve datos y error usando esa clase, ademas debes pasar el grid como parametro

entonces cuando invoques la funcionalidad usarias

```
ActualizarBodegaResult result = ActualizarBodega(...);
```

y tendras acceso a error y datos

Comment: Me genera este error al final `No se puede convertir implicitamente en el tipo 'MvcApp.Aspx.Pedido.Detalle.ActualizarBodegaResult' en 'System.Web.Ui.Web.Webcontrols.CustomValidator'`

Comment: Te esta dando ese error pk o no cambiastes el tipo de dato que devuelve la función ActualizarBodega y sigue siendo CustomValidator o cuando haces la asignación a lo que te devuelve esa función tu variable que recibe la llamada a la función es de tipo CustomValidator. Debes revisar bien estas cosas y tratar de seguir al hilo la respuesta de Leandro.

Comment: revisa el ejemplo que puse y veras que debes devolver un ActualizarBodegaResult